# Need help booting Chromebook w/ chrubuntu back into Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

I have an Acer C7 chromebook. I've installed chrubuntu using [this technique here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qpjTzav3kw) No thumb drive, no SD card, just the hard drive. Initially, I could switch back to chrome OS using

sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 1 /dev/aps

with a similar command in Chrome OS (dev mode) to get back (map 1:5 in the above command).

The first 2-3 times worked, then I spent like 3 days only using Chrubuntu & installing some python libs. Now it gives the following error when I try the shell command above from Chrubuntu:

ERROR: cgpt add: Can't open /dev/aps: No such file or directory

Any advice out there? I'm in over my head. I'd rather not restore full Chrome OS & go from there; it took a long time & I'm not sure I won't land in the same hole, again.

Background (if relevant): I gave Chrubuntu 200 gigs, and chrome OS the rest. Initially, I had no desire to go back to chrome OS. I can browse the web and, more importantly, write code with vim locally. Installing python/numpy/scipy/matplotlib all went well. However, when web browsing, frequently the system slows to a crawl, which is annoying; chrome OS was better. Now I want to go back & forth, hacking in Chrubuntu and browsing in Chrome OS. But I can't. Hence the question.

Comment: I should add that when I go to /dev/ and ls the directory, I do not see aps there. I don't recall removing it.

Comment: As matty stated you may be swapping because it does not have enough ram and that would definitely slow things down. Another question would be is have you checked what is running in the background to see what is using the processor/memory using "ps aux", this will show every process running. dont close them all or you will crash your system but look for ones with large amounts of memory. As for what is slow the page load or just the entire system in general?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason your system is so slow when you browse the web is that you don't have a swap drive and only 2 GB of ram.  I'm not an expert here and am trying to recover my Chrome OS after a bit of a disastrous mistake that I'm working on fixing.  So, I can't tell you exactly the best way to do that, but if you search google for "Make linux swap partition" you should find some good info.  I expect your slowness browsing will improve.

Also, there is this article that I followed to install ChrUbuntu that looks like it has the answer to your question: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/12/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-acers-199-c7-chromebook/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `cgpt`. Just open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install cgpt`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and retry

Comment: OP already has cgpt installed, otherwise the op wouldn't be using the command sudo cgpt